# "on (the) event day" and "on (the) celebration day"

Tags: articles, definite-article

I am going to write down two sentences below.

> 1. On **(the)** event day, we will have photos taken together.
> 2. On **(the)** celebration day, we will have photos taken together.

Do I need the definite article *the* in my sentences?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd say "the event day" or "the celebration day". Rather, I'd say "the day of the event" or "the day of the celebration".

If the day has a name, you don't need the article: "On Labor Day, we will have photos taken together." So if you name the day after the celebration, you could say "On Celebration Day, we will have photos taken together." But if it's just the day on which a celebration is occurring, use "the": "On the day of the celebration, we will have photos taken together."

Answer (score 1):

More usually it is said

> on the day of the **event**
>   on the day of the **party**
>   on the day of the **wedding**
>   on the day of the **celebration**

For example

> on the wedding day

has a slightly different feel than

> on the day of the **wedding**

and the former usually has a possessive attached to it "*their* wedding day", "*her* wedding day", the latter nicely makes a distinction between "*the wedding*" (ceremony) and the "*day*" of the ceremony.

When the context is know, many Brits will simply say

> on the day
>   *on the day we will all meet in the pub beforehand*